# unterminated string literal in javascript push() in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've used push() to push value with html code into an array but it seems that after double quotes WP(WordPress) automatically terminates the html code. Code is as below:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 
            xdr.onload=function() {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                var rAray = [];
                for (var i=0, tot=data.length; i < tot; i++) {
                    rAray.push('<div class="mm-rArr" style="border-bottom: #f0f0f0 dotted 1px;padding: 10px 0px;text-align: center;">' + data[i] + '</div><p>');
                }
                $('.mm-rAray').html(rAray);
            }   
            xdr.open("GET", "URL to API");
            xdr.send();
        }
        else {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "URL to API",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var rAray = [];
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        rAray.push('<div class="mm-rAray" style="border-bottom: #f0f0f0 dotted 1px;padding: 10px 0px;text-align: center;">' + val + '</div><p>');
                    });
                    console.log(rAray);
                    $('.mm-rAray').html(rAray.join(''));
                }
            });
        }
```

Error says **unterminated string literal at rAray.push('**

I've tried with creating an element by

```
$('div').addClass('mm-rAray').text(val);
```

too but same error comes at location $('. Don't know what's wrong there. Please help me to figure out this issue.

Comment: So where is `review.push()` ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, its rAray.push(). I edited the question